# Basic Help for Geojson with d3

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I am new to d3 and geojson.
I read the articles for d3. I understood almost all.
Now I new to create a map of canada with geojson and d3.

I am reading the article

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

I installed GDAL. Then I tried installing Node.js as mentioned in the article.

Automatic cmd got opened.

> npm install -g topojson ( I gave this command)
>   npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell.

(Press Control-D to exit.)

> install -g topojson ( I gave this command)
>   ...

I dont know, how to proceed further. 
From the articles also, I am unable to get what files should be downloaded. I even dont know, what things I should use. 
I just want to create a map of canada with d3 and geojson. Thats all I know. 
I am totally new. Please help me out. I know, this is very silly thing.

Is there any change I need to make with environmental variable ??

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install anything for a basic map. Have a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2322933). All you need to do is load your GeoJSON for Canda instead of the one for the UK. If you don't have a suitable GeoJSON file, just google it.

Comment: I have taken the data from: 

http://www.timegenie.com/latitude_and_longitude/state_coordinates/cans

used the same example as you mentioned.

The graph that is coming is quite awkward.

Can you help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "quite awkward"? It's not supposed to be centred or zoomed properly. Have a look at the examples on the d3 wiki for how to do things like that.

Comment: I mean the shape i am getting is quite awkward..
It is not the shape of a map or something..it is coming some awkward squares and random lines.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there. Try [this geojson](https://raw.github.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/CAN.geo.json) for example.

Comment: here i am getting perfect map..
would you tel me..wer would be canada.json file..
for every canada state and city, i get from..i am registered in github..just registered..

Comment: Have a look around the web. Google for "canada geojson" should be a good start.